# data.table fread function

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I am using the new `data.table:::fread` function (fastest read function I've used in R so far) and I got the following (self explanatory) exception:

```
R) fread(path)
Erreur dans fread(path) : Coercing integer64 to real needs to be implemented
```

My file (which is a csv separated by tabs) indeed holds big integers like `902160000671352000`. My question is then, can I tell `fread` to #NOT# read the second columns (where those monsters int are)

Comment: might be easier to tell `fread` to read in those columns as characters or factors.  Then you've got the data and can always do a type conversion later on.

Comment: My solution at the moment is to use the `cut -f1,3- myFile.txt` unix command and to run fread afterwards...

Comment: The `help(fread)` states that `bit64::integer64 types are also detected and read
     directly without needing to read as character then convert` I am using a 32bit OS (XP). Is that a problem ? can I convert those int64 into a char ?

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the docs; since this is a new function in a development version of the package, it seems that contacting the maintainer with this question might be a good idea ... (it feels in general like it would be a good idea for `fread` to allow a `colClasses` argument: even if it isn't needed most of the time because the autodetection is fantastic, there are always cases where you want to override (including skipping columns, which is done when the relevant element of colClasses is `NULL`) (@CarlWitthoft: nice idea but it looks like you can't do that in `fread` [yet])

Comment: What about using the "drop" option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question. Not yet, but yes you will be able to. Agree with all comments.

The TO DO list is at the top of the [readfile.c source](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/readfile.c?view=markup&root=datatable). If there's anything missing please let me know. That list covers allowing type overrides, implementing the unimplemented coercions and allowing columns to be skipped. Hopefully will all be done for first release in 1.9.0.

`fread` is currently in v1.8.7 which is in development on R-Forge. When finished it'll be released as 1.9.0 to CRAN. The .0 indicates that new features might possibly change argument names and behaviour; i.e., don't be surprised if backwards incompatabile changes are made to `fread` in 1.9.1. Given its nature it's hard to imagine anything major will change, though.  But that's why I publicised its availability on R-Forge, to get it into the wild early and get things like this right.